# ifconfig ip address does not show server ip address

Tags: linux, ip

I'm allowed to access a server via ssh. I was given the ip address and port number of ssh service. The operating system of the server is ubuntu 18.04. But running `ifconfig` on the server does not show the ip address which I use to connect the server. What are some possible explanations?

Answer (score 3):

*Meta note: Asking for a list of things does not necessarily fit the site because it invites partial answers that only collectively form a complete(-ish) list. This answer is community wiki and hopefully users will improve it (add to it) instead of posting additional possibilities as separate answers.*

---

Possible explanations:

1. [DNAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#DNAT).

   > DNAT is commonly used to publish a service located in a private network on a publicly accessible IP address.

   In this case `ifconfig` will show you the private IP address. The public address you used belongs to another machine.
2. The SSH daemon and/or the shell on the server you originally logged in to is configured to silently connect you to another machine. This is somewhat similar to DNAT, but works on SSH/shell level.
3. Multiple IPv4  addresses, [but `ifconfig` shows just one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/672090/108618). Invoke `ip address` to see more.

The explanations are not mutually exclusive. It's possible to configure things, so more than one contributes to what you see.

Answer (score 1):

`ifconfig` has been [deprecated](https://ubuntu.com/blog/if-youre-still-using-ifconfig-youre-living-in-the-past) in Ubuntu 18.04, as it is in many if not all current Linux distros. It's replaced by `ip`.

Check `ip addr` in your own system. Then go to [whatismyip.com](https://www.whatismyip.com/). If you have a regular ISP connection, your `ip addr` will show something like 192.168.1.100, while whatismyip.com shows something completely different. Whatismyip.com will show the public IP address of your router.

The router NATs the traffic between internal network and internet. With most SoHo routers you can create port forwarding rules in your router so the ingress traffic to specific port is forwarded to a specific system.

If you're accessing the server over the internet, similarly the IP address you use to connect to the server is unlikely to be the actual server's IP but the network's internet router's external (public) IP, and the router has similar rule to forward all ingress traffic to port 22 to a specific internal IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you might be behind proxies/bastions or some other networking-trick so they configured the external IP that you access with in another place and forwarded it to your server ( or some other explanation ) in such cases - you won't see the external IP address configured in your server.

Personally, I run `curl ipinfo.io` to see more information about the server i'm running, it's kind of a "looking glass" on how the "world" sees your server, and it outputs something like:

```
{
  "ip": "<your external IP>",
  "city": "...",
  "region": "...",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "...",
  "org": "<company that owns this server>",
  "postal": "...",
  "timezone": "...",
  "readme": "https://ipinfo..."
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).